# Use .net object as data source in Crystal Report 2008

Tags: .net, datasource, crystal-reports-2008

HI all,

I created a .net object (ex: `A`) which contain data have been collected from tables.
Next, i create a `List<A>()` and pass to `SetDataSource()` method of `ReportDocument` object.
When i run then an Exception have been throwed :

```
"CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.DataSourceException: The data source object is invalid"
```

I don't know the Exception above, Error message isn't clear. Can anybody explain for me? ex: the .net object must inherit from ISerializable.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same error, but encountered it when using an object as the data source for the report. I had the following code:

```
var myObj = new MyDataObject();
cr.Load(@"C:\report.rpt");
cr.SetDataSource(myObj);
```

and got the same error.

Changing the SetDataSource line to this:

```
cr.SetDataSource(new [] { myObj });
```

helped and it is now working correctly.
In other words, try wrapping your object in an array. If you're using a list, try converting it to an array first (use the .ToArray() method).