# DataSource object is invalid in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm using `asp.net mvc 4` and `Crystal Report` to make a receipt where datas are stored in MSSQL db and user can download the receipt as pdf file. For some reason, everytime I try to download, I get an error,

> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.DataSourceException: The data source object is invalid.

Here are the codes,

```
    public ActionResult ExtractReceipt()
    {
        var getOwner = rentdb.OwnerRegs.Where(a => a.username == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        var getId = getOwner.serial;

        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
        rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Invoice.rpt")));
        rd.SetDataSource(rentdb.Invoices.Where(a => a.owner_id == getId).FirstOrDefault());
        Response.Buffer = false;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return File(stream, "application/pdf", "MyReceipt.pdf");
    }
```

Is there anything wrong in my code? How can I solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: try wrapping your object in an array. If you're using a list, try converting it to an array first (use the .ToArray() method). Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2592203/795683

Comment: No, I'm not using the report to list records. It'll just fetch one record.

Comment: i think this line is returning multiple records instead of one:
rentdb.Invoices.Where(a => a.owner_id == getId).FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Nope, I've only one record in my db now, and the id is unique for every records in my db.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this

```
 var query=rentdb.Invoices.Where(a => a.owner_id == getId).FirstOrDefault();

 var querylist = new List<Invoices> { query };

 rd.SetDataSource(querylist);
```

Comment: good solution.It is an important step to turn one item into a list first.

Answer (score 0):

You Need To Change FirstOrDefault() to ToList();

```
public ActionResult ExtractReceipt()
{
    var getOwner = rentdb.OwnerRegs.Where(a => a.username == 
    User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
    var getId = getOwner.serial;

    ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
    rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Invoice.rpt")));
    rd.SetDataSource(rentdb.Invoices.Where(a => a.owner_id == getId).ToList()); //FirstOrDefault() Need To Change
    Response.Buffer = false;
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return File(stream, "application/pdf", "MyReceipt.pdf");
}
```